# How do I enumerate web part types in WSS site

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, wss

How would I go about enumerating the web part types available to be deployed to a web part page in a particular SPWeb by a user on a WSS 3.0 site?  Sort of the equivalent of the list that you'd get via the "Add Web Part" link, but in a collection so that they could be instantiated and then added to a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this excellent post which enumerates the contents of the WebPart Gallery and can then instantiate any type found:

[Add Web Part To SharePoint Page](http://neganov.blogspot.com/2007/11/add-web-part-to-sharepoint-page.html)